# How do i avoid MidAir jumps in Unity using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a jumping Script, i got so far, the problem is that i do not want the gameObject to jump midair

I tried using OnCollisionStay/Enter together with OnCollisionExit to generate a bool which gets checked together with Input before jumping, this worked the best but unity is missing triggers

I cant check for position with gameObject.transform.position.y because i have differently elevated platforms.

isGrounded works with a different code but it interferes with my other movements (which are implemented by AddForce on Input)

I can't wrap my head around why this code doesn't work, i hope someone can help me understand.

```
using UnityEngine
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform PPos; 
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
}
    public void Update()
{

    if(controller.isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
      rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0);
      Debug.Log("Jump Executed");
    }
}
```

I don't get a Syntax Error

Comment: Are you setting `controller.isGrounded` anywhere in your collision code?

Comment: No i have not, i have CharacterController in the PlayerMovement Script connected to the CharacterController Component in Unity.
Here is my Collision Code
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2em3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

You need to set the `controller.isGrounded` whenever your character has the ability to jump.

#### PlayerScript

```
void OnCollisionEnter(collision other)
{
    controller.isGrounded = other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground");
}
```

---

### Original

If you want to jump in mid-air, you're going to have to remove the condition that your character controller is on the ground.

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
```

Comment: Thats the code i had before, i try to avoid midair jumps. The problem is the script does not consider the gameObject on ground. Even though it is due to the scene gravity.

Comment: Then I would rewrite your question a little to say that you would like to not have your character jump in midair.